# Uncaught ReferenceError: CRM is not defined when trying to access mail templates

Tags: error, mailing

When I try to create and new, or edit an existing, message template in 'Mailings' > 'Messsage Templates' I end up at a completely unstyled page. When I look at the console I see the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: CRM is not defined
at BtJa0AvQ:153
```

I then look at the 'file' that is being referenced and at the very last line I see:

```
})(CRM.$);
```

I have a Test server which is rendering the mail templates fine, it's simply the Prod server (which figures...) where I'm having this issue.

Any ideas where I can troubleshoot this issue?

I'm using the following:

- Drupal 7.56
- CiviCRM 4.7.22
- PHP 5.5.38
- Amazon Linux AMI release 2017.03
- Apache 2.4.27

I'm only using one extension but that extension has nothing to do with mailing and was actually added well after this problem surfaced.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to indicate the CiviCRM version and CMS you're using?  Are you using any extensions that affect mail, like Mosaico and/or Flexmailer?

Comment: Thanks for the updated info!  I can give you some troubleshooting ideas now (see below)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some places to check:

- The JavaScript file name you mentioned shows that you're using aggregated JavaScript.  To troubleshoot this, temporarily [disable aggregated Javascript](https://www.drupal.org/node/2866077).
- If that solves your problem by itself, it's probably just a caching issue.  Clear caches and reenable JS aggregation.  More likely though, it will just make debugging easier (e.g. by showing the actual JS file throwing the error).
- Use the "Network" tab in your browser's developer tools once JS aggregation is off to look for 404 errors.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I do have JS aggregation turned off. I just added $config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = TRUE; to my settings.php file as per the post that you linked to, just to verify. I'm still getting the same results. One of the errors I neglected to add to the error message is: 'civicrm/admin/messageTemplates/add?action=add&reset=1 500 (Internal Server Error)'

Comment: You may be getting the same results - but if your JS is no longer aggregated, then your console should report the JS error in a different filename, which should be a clue.  Did you find any 404 errors?

Comment: I didn't see any 404 errors but there was the following 500 error:
GET https://www.example.org/civicrm/admin/messageTemplates/add?action=add&reset=1 500 (Internal Server Error)

Where 'example' is replacing the actual URL. So for some reason even after setting my JS not to aggregate it's still aggregating.

Comment: I found that in the file sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/PDF/Document.php there is a line require_once 'TbsZip/tbszip.php that was throwing the following error in the Drupal logs: Warning: require_once(TbsZip/tbszip.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in require_once() (line 34 of /var/www/html/EXAMPLE/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/PDF/Document.php). I commented that line out and now everything seems to work. Not sure what the repercussions of that are, or why it works on Test and not Prod.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue and found that civicrm/packages/TbsZip/tbszip.php file is missing. Restoring the file fixed this issue.